# iFrame and Textarea Editor Live Preview and "Designer Mode" with activeElement

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I am making an editor with live preview which means that when I type `HTML` codes inside the `textarea`, it will automatically show inside the `iFrame` and I currently have the following code to select the active element in the `iFrame`: `document.getElementById("IFRAME").contentWindow.document.activeElement` but how can I make it so that when I click an element inside the `iFrame`, it will select the element's source that I wrote in the `textarea`? A concept would be nice too.

My initial concept was:

When I click on an `element` inside the `iframe`,  it will get the `innerHTML` of the `activeElement` and search for it in the `textarea` but the problem with that is what if the user has more than one of same `elements` with the same `innerHTML`? So that wouldn't work.

Rough Code (Just For Concept):

HTML:

```
<iframe id="IFRAME"></iframe>
<textarea id="TEXTAREA" onkeyup="update()">
    <div id="clickme">
    </div>
</textarea>
```

JAVASCRIPT:

```
function update() {
document.getElementById('IFRAME') = document.getElementById('TEXTAREA').innerHTML;
}

function IFRAME_ELEMENT_CLICKED() {
    // When "clickme" is clicked from inside the iframe, select the innerHTML generated in the TEXTAREA
    // document.getElementById("IFRAME").contentWindow.document.activeElement ....
}
```

Comment: Can you show some HTML code... it's a bit hard to work out what you're trying to do.

Comment: I need help with the `IFRAME_ELEMENT_CLICKED()` function.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In my opinion, while you generate preview onto the iFrame from textarea, you should create dom elements by including a specifier which acts as a link between the content in the textarea and that of the iFrame. You can probably start assigning an id to each tag that you generate onto the iFrame which can be the cursor position/char index etc., in the text area (This needs more manipulation that what I mention here as you need to re-assign the IDs in iFrame, as not always everyone types text at the end in the textarea).

This way you would be able to capture the exact position of content on textarea when someone makes a selection on the iFrame.

Comment: So you're suggesting that I make a list with a layout such as `ID:EXACTPOSITION` and on the `TEXTAREA`'s `onkeyup` function, before updating the `IFRAME`, I replace all the `ID`'s behind the scenes and when they click the `activeElement`, it will select the `EXACTPOSITION` by getting the `activeElement`'s `ID`?